# Conditionally color material icon in VueJS method?

Tags: vue.js, icons, conditional-statements, material-design, quasar-framework

I'm building an app with Quasar v0.15.9, Vue v2.5.0 and material icons. I have a Quasar collapsible inside a Quasar list

```
<q-list class="q-ma-none q-pa-none" v-for="(fiberPhase, index) in salesRepPhases" :key="index">
    <q-collapsible 
      :label="'Phase ' + fiberPhase.fiber_phase + ' ' + '(' + fiberPhase.fiber_status + ')'" 
      :icon="fiberIcon(fiberPhase.fiber_status)">
      <PhaseToBlocks :fiberPhase="fiberPhase.fiber_phase" />
    </q-collapsible>
  </q-list>
```

I am passing the `fiber_status` per list item to a VueJS method that is setting the icon:

```
methods: {
  fiberIcon: function (status) {
    if (status === 'Live') {
      return 'fiber_manual_record'

    if (status === 'Pending') {
      return 'fiber_manual_record'
    }
    return 'fiber_manual_record'
  }
}
```

I could set to three different icons, but what I would prefer to do is set to the same icon and set the icon color per the three statuses. Anyone see a way that would be possible? The style is set component level and I also have `stylus` as part of Quasar. The colors I want to set are stylus variables, which can be set inline or in the style tag per usual VueJS standards:

```
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
@import '~variables'

.q-item:focus
  background $secondary

.q-list-header 
  text-align center
  background $tertiary
  color white

</style>
```

Here's an example of the list with non-colored icons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not that will be that common of a question, but I figured it out with a `<q-icon />`, rather than the bound `:icon` attribute:

```
<q-icon class="q-pa-sm" name="fiber_manual_record" :class="fiberIcon(fiberPhase.fiber_status)"/>
```

I then was able to return classes and set to stylus variables:

```
.live
  color $positive
.pending
  color $negative
.provisioning
  color $warning
```

For an end result of this:

[image]